# how to find quartiles of nsarray of integers in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a large nsarray of integers.  I would like to determine the different quartiles.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How would you do it anywhere else?

Comment: You sort the elements, then find a value 25%, 50%, 75% of the way into the sorted array. How else?

Comment: Unless sorting is prohibitive, sort and pick values at 1/4, 1/2, and 3/4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSInteger q1Index = [sortedArray count] / 4;
NSInteger q2Index = [sortedArray count] / 2;
NSInteger q3Index = q2Index + q1Index;
NSInteger q1 = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:q1Index] integerValue];
NSInteger q2 = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:q2Index] integerValue];
NSInteger q3 = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:q3Index] integerValue];
```

q1, q2, q3 are now set to the quartile values.

Comment: Close.  `q1` can't be an NSInteger.  It could be an NSNumber or NSValue.

Comment: yes, of course you're right. response edited (assuming the nsarray contains nsnumbers)